# OpenGL Raster Transformation not yielding expected results

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, raster

There don't seem to be a lot of examples online of how to properly use the raster transformation methods provided with OpenGL.

I've drawn a simple triangle, and I am trying to merely copy the triangle and redraw it somewhere else. I'm getting very unusual results that I don't understand:

Given the triangle (pink): verts [3] = { {10.0, 25.0}, {125.0, 25.0}, {60.0, 60} };

I displayed the triangle:

```
glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);  // Clear display window.
glColor3f (1.0, 0.5, 0.5);      // Set initial fill color (pink).
triangle (verts);           // Display colored triangle.
```

I then did the following in an effort to redraw the triangle via raster transformations:

```
GLubyte *data [115][35];
glReadPixels(10, 25, 115, 35, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
glRasterPos2i(50,100);  
glDrawPixels(35, 115, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
```

What I thought this was doing was copying all the pixels starting at (10, 25) moving right and up 300 pixels. This more than encompass the triangle.

I thought that by then drawing the pixels it would merely draw them identically as they are, but instead it is drawing a gray box that I don't even remotely understand.

What is the proper use of `glReadPixels(...);` and `glDrawPixels(...)`?

Why is my current use giving a gray box and in no way copying or drawing the pixels in the image?

[image]

Comment: You are aware that `glDrawPixels (...)` uses a separate part of the API known as the raster position, correct? I don't see anywhere where you are establishing this value, and if the raster position is invalid (clipped) lots of funny things will happen.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman no, I was not aware that `glDrawPixels(...)` used a different API. I'm new to OpenGL and have been struggling with raster transformations. Are there any examples out there that you're aware of that actually demonstrate this process?

Comment: It's not a different API, just a different part (a removed part in GL 3.1) of the API. Whereas `glReadPixels (...)` lets you read from an arbitrary location in the read buffer, `glDrawPixels (...)` is relative to the raster position, which you set with `glRasterPos* (...)`. Also you should allocate your pixel data this way: `GLubyte data [300 * 300 * 3];` instead of what you have now.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman So I changed the `GLubyte` part and added a raster postion to move the object, but it's still showing as a gray rectangle. How should I properly be reading the pixels from the buffer?

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman I've updated the question. This shows the line now being drawn where the raster position indicates, but the pixels that are being "read" and/or the pixels being "drawn" are not the pixels within the range given, since those are obviously a big pink triangle.

Comment: The raster position set with `glRasterPos2i (...)` is in object-space coordinates (same as a call to `glVertex2i (...)`). If you want those coordinates to be relative to the window, you have to do a lot of extra work. If you have an OpenGL 1.4+ implementation, the easier solution would be to use `glWindowPos2i (...)` (this sets the raster position in window-space). Also, you keep making an array of pointers by doing things like this: `GLubyte *data [...]`. You don't want that, you want an array: `GLubyte data [...]`.

Comment: You are getting lucky in that a pointer is probably 4 or 8 bytes on your system, and your RGB color requires 3 bytes of storage. An array of pointers, therefore, is large enough to hold the pixel data. But the correct way to create your array of pixel data is actually something along the lines of `GLubyte data [ResX][ResY][3]`. ResX * ResY pixels, 3-bytes each.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Is there any way to bring this to chat without it prompting you? This comment chain is getting out of control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### After a lengthy chat, a few issues were exposed:

1. `GL_RGB` pixels are not well liked by `glReadPixels (...)` and `glDrawPixels (...)`

   - Using the default pixel store, GL tries to store each row it reads on a 4-byte boundary; 3-byte RGB pixels make an absolute mess out of this and many other things in OpenGL.
   - You must call `glPixelStorei (GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, 1)` before `glReadPixels (...)` with a `GL_RGB` format, or it may pad the end of each row in the ***output*** with extra bytes to satisfy 4-byte row alignment. Left unchecked, the default alignment will eventually lead to a memory overrun.
   - Likewise, you need to use `glPixelStorei (GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1)` before `glDrawPixels (...)` so that it does not try to skip bytes to maintain 4-byte alignment while reading rows from your ***input*** data.
2. Your array was declared incorrectly, you were allocating an array of pointers.

   - A pointer to a `GLubyte` is considerably larger than a `GLubyte` itself (4-8x as large depending on the compiler / CPU).
   - The proper way to declare your pixel array is `GLubyte data [115 * 35 * 3]`, to store 115 * 35 pixels, each 3-bytes.
3. The raster position is in object-space coordinates, but the position in `glReadPixels (...)` is in window-space coordinates.

   - Without an appropriate projection matrix, viewport, etc. the scale between coordinate systems (object and window) will not match, and you cannot accurately say that your triangle is 115 ***pixels*** tall and 35 ***pixels*** wide (those are its object-space dimensions).